# Generate Custom Order Number

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried to generate custom order number. My MySQL table is like:
tblOrder
id int(11) AI; ordno varchar(50);

I try to use following function inside php block as **before record added event** to accomplish this.

```
{

$sql="select max(substr(ordno,9)) as mx from ord where substr(ordno,7,2)=month(now())  order by mx";
$rs=CustomQuery($sql);
$data=db_fetch_array($rs);
$str="OR-";
$str2=date("Ymd");
$str3=($data["mx"]+1);
$values["ordno"]="$str$str2".str_pad($str3, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);}
```

Problem is when I run this code it always give me same order number like OR-2014013000001 for all record entry. It does not change. Could you please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real issue is being hidden by the way you're parsing the composite `ordno` column. Remember that SUBSTRING is 1-based, not zero-based indexing.

```
$sql="select max(substring(ordno,12, 5)) as mx from ord where
      substring(ordno, 8, 2)=month(now())  order by mx";
```

...seems to be the correct parsing to get the values you want.

It really would be better to store the order data in separate fields instead of encoding meaning into a single column. You may be stuck with it this way, but if you CAN edit it, why not compute the order number on the fly by grabbing a well structured `date` order date column and an `int` order sequence column?

Comment: @Kortoa Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please accept this answer if it's working (as well as for your other questions that you've asked).

Comment: I appreciate your nice tips. I don't know much about php program but learning. I usually do numbering by date("ymdHis") function. I am not clear about the 2nd part of your explanantion how I can use order date in conjunction with orderid to create custom number. Thanks again.

Comment: If you had two fields in the database, one DATE field and one INT field, you could calculate or produce the order number by assembling it into the structure you want instead of having to PARSE it as you are doing into the date and int components. In general, columns should mean and store just one thing -- not a combination of dates and sequences and other data.